# Creating a trigger instead of UPDATE on a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, cursor

I have a view and a trigger that overwrites UPDATE. I try to understand the code, however I am having some troubles with line `from deleted` and `from inserted` - Are these automatically created by original update? Does it mean that if I call this trigger, first the update gets called and then the trigger?

```
create trigger updateView on View
instead of UPDATE as
begin
    declare @nameK VARCHAR(100), @addresK VARCHAR(100), @nameZ VARCHAR(100), @number INT, @date DATE;
    declare @nameKo VARCHAR(100), @addresKo VARCHAR(100), @nameZo VARCHAR(100), @numbero INT, @dateo DATE; -- 'o'ld

    declare insCur cursor for select name, addres, bandName, number, date from inserted;
    declare delCur cursor for select name, addres, bandName, number, date  from deleted;
    open insCur;
    open delCur;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This trigger will fire instead of performing the update. The `inserted` and `deleted` tables are made available so that you can determine:

1. The new values for each updated row in `inserted`
2. The previous (in this case current, since the normal update operation has not been performed) values from each updated row in `deleted`

The convention of `inserted` and `deleted` is used regardless of the type of trigger. So, for example, in an `after update` trigger, which simply follows the execution of a normal update, the `deleted` table would be the primary way to know the previous values.

Answer (score 0):

The deleted contains old values, the inserted - new values.
There are options: AFTER UPDATE or BEFORE UPDATE which you can set to see behavior which you want.

About Deleted and Inserted: 
UPDATE dbo.Client SET Name = 'John' WHERE Name = 'Steve'
you will have: deleted value 'Steve', inserted value 'John'

Also I would recommend to avoid using cursors inside triggers, i.e. it can hit performance a lot.